# testing springboog kafka @sendTo with SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using the `@SendTo("example")` annotation to send messages to a topic
but I don't know how to test it.
I open a console producer

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic example
```

in the console seems to work, but I don't receive any message in the producer

```
gid: trace= span= [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata Cluster ID: uX-1vV4bSFup6t_Sh_LNCg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in the console seems to work, but I don't receive any message in the producer

Remember this:

- The **producer** only **produces** (sends) messages
- The **consumer** only **consumes** (receives) messages

If you already produce messages to a certain topic using `@SendTo` annotation, you can test the consummation using the [`kafka-console-consumer.sh`](https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.0.3/kafka-managing/topics/kafka-manage-cli-consumer.html) utility subscribed to the same `example` topic:

```
kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh \
--bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic example --from-beginning
```

If you send messages via producer (programmatically using `@SendTo` annotation) correctly, you should be able to see them in the console.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try any open source GUI tool like [kafka tool](http://www.kafkatool.com/)
makes life a lot easier when the use case is local debugging and testing.